# Connected to VPN Unable to Connect to Server Connected to different VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, rdp

I am Connected to our VPN and I would like to RDP to a Server that is on the network that is currently connected to a different VPN.  What do we need to do?  If I RDP to a different server and then RDP from that server to the one connected to a different VPN, it works.  I just can't directly.  Is there something that we need to set up on that server, my computer or the network?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can be connected to other remote server as well with your machine as VPN client so now will be vpn client to two different vpn server

for doing this you need to perform following steps
1.Create a new client1.conf file for the new remote server
2.copy the content of already present client.conf to client1.conf file
3.now change the value of ca, cert and keys in client1.conf file to the respective values as per to those needed to connect other remote server
4.establish vpn connection with other remote server as follows

```
openvpn client1.conf
```

The command used above are for linux to establish vpn using openvpn, For windows, please find same command for windows from openvpn site might be client1.conf in linux corresponds to client1.opvf or something... However this would be the step to be performed in general